# shinyapps setAccountInfo error

Tags: r, shiny

When I tried to configure my `shinyapps` with account info registered on my.shinyapps.io according to the guideline on https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/blob/master/guide/guide.md,

**Call sth like this with my real account name, token and secret:**
    shinyapps::setAccountInfo(name="", token="", secret="")

**Error:**
    Error: /v1/users/current 403 - bad signature

**SessionInfo**
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

```
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

other attached packages:
    [1] shinyapps_0.2  devtools_1.4.1

```
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.5.1 httr_0.2       memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.2 RCurl_1.95-4.1
 [7] RJSONIO_1.0-3  stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2    whisker_0.3-2
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Try installing a latest version of `devtools` .Have you installed all the dependency packages?

Comment: I've installed the latest devtools_1.4.1. You could see from attached packages.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure, you provide the correct values for all 3 Parameters in the rsconnect call, when trying to connect to your account from RStudio:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>',
              token='<YOUR_TOKEN>',
              secret='<SECRET>')
```

YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME: This is the name of your account as configured when creating your shinyapps.io-Account.

YOUR_TOKEN: This is a valid token. You can add/delete Tokens in your shinyapps.io - Account within your profile-settings.

SECRET: This is a generated Hash from your passphrase which you have to configure in your shinyapps.io - Account within your profile-settings as well. It must not be left empty (it initially is empty, when logging in using your Google or Github-Account). You have to explicitely click the 'show secret' Button within the Token-Page of your Profile to display the required hash-value needed for SECRET.

Answer (score 4):

There is an outstanding [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/issues/19) in the shinyapps package that causes signature calculation issues when using non english locales.

The work around is to set your locale to en_US before running setAccountInfo() by running:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

Comment: `Sys.setlocale(locale="English")` for Windows systems.